# Tk DSL lose access to instance methods and variables?

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

I know this is not specific to tk, but rather a more general problem with ruby DSLs and instance_eval, but here is my question, if I want to use the DSL for tk, I can't figure out how to make certain things work. For example, if I want to call a instance method by pressing a button, this will not work, because it thinks I am trying to call a method with the same name in the Tk parent class (i.e. Tk::Button) as in the below code:

```
require 'tk'
class MyApp
  def initialize
    @root = TkRoot.new
    TkFrame.new {|f|
      TkButton.new(f) {
        text "Press Me"
        command proc {do_something()}
        pack
      }
      pack
    }
  end
  def do_something
    puts "Hello!"
  end
  def run
    Tk.mainloop
  end
end

MyApp.new.run
```

If I rewrite it not using the DSL, I can avoid this issue, but I prefer the DSL for various reasons:

```
class MyApp
  def initialize
    @root = TkRoot.new
    f = TkFrame.new
    TkButton.new(f, text: "Press Me", command: proc {do_something()}).pack
    f.pack
  end
  def do_something
    puts "Hello!"
  end
  def run
    Tk.mainloop
  end
end

MyApp.new.run
```

The same is true for instance variables of the MyApp class. Is there any way arround this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`proc { do_something }` is probably being evaluated in the context of the `TkButton` instance. That's probably how you can call `text`, `command` and `pack` while inside the block.

This effectively means `self` is not the `MyApp` instance anymore; it was changed to the `TkButton` instance.

Try this:

```
def initialize
  my_app = self  # self is the MyApp instance here
  @root = TkRoot.new
  TkFrame.new do |f|
    TkButton.new f do
      text "Press Me"
      command proc { my_app.do_something }
      pack
    end
    pack
  end
end
```

Since blocks are closures, the `my_app` local variable will be available to the block.